# System.ServiceModel.FaultException1 when deploying Azure MVC tutorial project to local runtime

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure

I'm trying to get trough the Azure MVC tutorial from MS, this one: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/

And when I get to step 7 under the part "MAKING YOUR APPLICATION READY TO DEPLOY TO WINDOWS AZURE" Visual Studio 2010 just hangs and gives me the following log for failing:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled
  Message=This access control list is not in canonical form and therefore cannot be modified.
  Source=mscorlib
  Action=http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher/fault
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at IConfigurator.Deploy(String roleId, WebAppModel webAppModelPath, String roleRootDirectory, String sitesDestinationRootDirectory, String diagnosticsRootDirectory, String roleGuid, Dictionary`2 globalEnvironment)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.WaIISHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
  InnerException:
```

Anyone that has a idea of what can be wrong? I have a suspicion that the config string that is inputed in part 6. might be wrong, this one:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet_ToDoListApp;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

this is located in the Web.config file but I am not sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out eventually thanks to this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/15312fe7-ed22-4903-81a0-41404fabf9f3/
and this post:
http://sergecalderara.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/systemservicemodelfaultexception1-was-unhandled-by-user-code/ post.

Basically I removed the  tag from ServiceDefinition.csdef in the Azure package of the project and disabled some debugging options. Strange that the default config for the project fails to build when the tutorial says nothing about this.